# FQL: How to use an array in an fql statement?

Tags: arrays, facebook-fql

How to use an array instead of $id in the line below,

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=" . $id;
```

So it becomes like:

```
$array[0] = "12345678";
$array[1] = "87654321";
$fql = "SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=" . $array;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `in` operator:

```
$array[0] = "12345678";
$array[1] = "87654321";
$fql = "SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid in (".
       implode(',', $array). 
       ")";
```